# NoSQL that supports Fluent queries in .NET

Tags: .net, nosql, fluent

Coming from a strong SQL Server background, I'm starting to work with larger amounts of data that are less suited to a relational database, so I am looking at alternative possible NoSQL databases.

Are there any NoSQL engines that support fluent LINQ queries (excepting relational queries)?

Comment: I realise that fluent queries should not be the primary consideration when choosing a database engine, but with no prior NoSQL experience and all else being equal, some familiarity would help.

Comment: a bit old, but SisoDb has support for lambda expressions http://sisodb.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) has strong LINQ support.

In fact, you use LINQ to define indexes and queries.

Comment: Good suggestions, but too expensive for commercial projects when so many alternatives are available.

Comment: @FreshCode - You didn't specify anywhere in your question that you are looking for a free solution.

Comment: not necessarily free, just affordable for a startup. I guess the $25/month/instance isn't so bad, but I'd like all databases to have a free data-limited version like SQL Server Express.

Comment: @FreshCode - Again, something you should have specified in your question. $599 one time payment is not that much either.